# Setting Rule Parameters such as ignoreFontFamilies

Tags: parameters, rules, sonarcloud

In SonarCloud where/how would I set the parameters for specific rules?

For example, more specifically, I am needing to set "ignoreFontFamilies" on the CSS rule "Font declarations should contain at least one generic font family" (rule ID css:S4649) as shown below from their UI:

[image: Sonar Cloud ignoreFontFamilies]

To be clear, I am currently using the ["Automatic analysis"](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/automatic-analysis/) and have reviewed the [related document](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/analysis-parameters/) several times.

It claims that the UI can be used but I do not have an option related to parameters that I could add ignoreFontFamilies. It also mentions using a .sonarcloud.properties file but I cannot find anywhere in the docs that expands on the specific syntax of this file for editing something like ignoreFontFamilies specifically (I need to set it to the name of a custom icon font name in this case).

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone dealing with this in the future, I was able to get clarification through the Sonar Community Forums after several days.

You first need to navigate under quality profiles and extend the existing Sonar Way for your given language.

Then navigate under rules to find and select the relevant rule. At the bottom you are able to activate your quality profile and change the parameters for the selected rule as shown below:

[image]